# regex that will check expression is valid arithmetic expression, for example 'a+b*c=d' is valid and accepted

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I made separate regexs for both but its not giving desired result. and it should work like check whole input string and return valid if its valid or invalid if its invalid.

```
import re
identifiers = r'^[^\d\W]\w*\Z'
operators = r'[\+\*\-\/=]'
a = re.compile(identifiers, re.UNICODE)
b = re.compile(operators, re.UNICODE)
c = re.findall(a, 'a+b*c=d')
d = re.findall(b, 'a+b*c=d')
print c, 'identifiers'
print d, 'operators'
```

Result of this snippet is

```
[ ] identifiers &
['+', '*', '='] operators
```

**I want results like input string is valid or invalid by checking all characters of input string by both regex**

Comment: Generally, regexes don't deal well with recursively defined structures like arithmetic expressions.  You can perhaps use a regex to recognize tokens, but you'll probably need a parser to handle the structure of the arithmetic expression.

Comment: Why are you doing this as a regex?  And what will you do with the string after you've decided whether or not it's valid?  Are you trying to figure out if it's valid to send to `eval`?

Comment: yeah i m trying to check string first. @AndyLester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're having with your current code is that your `identifiers` pattern only works if it matches the whole string.

The problem is that the current pattern requires that both the beginning and end of the input be matched (by the `^` and `\Z` respectively). That's usually causing you to not finding any identifiers, since only an input like `"foo"` would be matched, since it's a single identifier that contacts both the start and end of the string. (I'd also note that it is a bit odd to mix `^` and `\Z` together, though it is not invalid. It would just be more natural to pair `^` with `$` or `\Z` with `\A`.)

I suspect that you don't actually want `^` and `\Z` in your pattern, but rather should be using `\b` in place of both. The `\b` escape matches "word breaks", which means either the start or end of the input, or a change between word-characters and non-word characters.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b[^\d\W]\w*\b', 'a+b*c=d', re.U) 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

This still isn't going to do what you say you ultimately want (testing if the string to ensure it's a valid expression). That's a much more difficult task, and regular expressions are not up to it in general. Certain specific forms of expressions can perhaps be matched with regex, but supporting things like parentheses will break the whole system in a hurry. To identify arbitrary arithmetic expressions, you'd need a more sophisticated parser, which might use regex in some of it's steps, but not for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple cases like your example an expression like this will work:

```
^[0-9a-z]+([+/*-][0-9a-z]+)+=[0-9a-z]+$
```

Comment: it is hard coded. There can be any type of strings.